# How to permanently change an UCM activity name?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I wanted to re-name my activity name from cleartool command-line using the commands

```
$ cleartool lsact
2016-04-14T17:10:17+05:30  foo_eg1  adam  "foo_eg1"

$ cleartool rename activity:foo_eg1@/vobs/fw-ucm activity:bar_eg1@/vobs/fw-ucm
Renamed activity from "foo_eg1" to "bar_eg1".

When I check for my activity name again:-   

$ cleartool lsact
2016-04-14T17:10:17+05:30 bar_eg1   adam "foo_eg1"

I can see the older activity name still pointed here and from the below command too.

$ ccase showact
..
title: foo_eg1
..
```

Why is the older activity name still referenced here?
Is there a way I can force change the name?
What other pitfalls should I be aware of when the names are different this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check "[Change the name of an activity from GUI or CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123180)":

> Every activity has a Headline and an ID.
>
> - The Headline is the visible description (or name) you see when performing a checkout or checkin of a file within a UCM view,
> - whereas the ID is an internal field that holds the name of the object in the VOB database.
>
> These can be identical, but that is not required.

```
cleartool chactivity -headline <new_headline> activity-id
```

What you did was changing the ID, not the activity headline.

Comment: Worked like charm! +1 and Accepted!