# Displaying comment 'title' in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

Is there any native way of only listing a comment's "title" in ClearCase? When I say title, I mean something similar to what Git has, where a comment of the type

```
Some title

Some detailed description of the comment...
```

when added, will mostly show up as only `Some title` in most Git commands, unless the user explicitly wants to see the full description.

Comment: The notion of title exists for UCM activities, but not for base ClearCase. The closest is to print the first line of what `cleartool describe –fmt "%c" afile` gives you. I'll put an answer later after work.

Comment: @VonC I'm starting to see a pattern here. Everything I want is already built into UCM, but we can't migrate to it.

Comment: There's can't and CAN'T. UCM isn't much more than the encapsulation of a number of best practices. And it simplifies the user experience for branches, labels, activity management, etc. From your last few questions,  I'm  guessing that there are multiple groups with different usage patterns, including fighting over a shared /main branch. Sounds like a "challenging" environment.

Comment: @BrianCowan It is and any attempt to try to improve anything is met with 'we don't need it, we've always done it like this and we were fine'.

Comment: @BrianCowan Changing to UCM is political,  since we don't control the development environment (central CAD group does and implements it for all divisions).  What a colleague and I started doing is implementing our own wrapper scripts over Base ClearCase that are heavily SVN/Git and UCM inspired.

Comment: @BrianCowan We intend to use our scripts for our code and hopefully they can catch on.

Comment: @BrianCowan At the same time,  I considered using an existing wrapper over ClearCase. I found one for Git but it wasn't really maintained. Do you or VonC know of any good one (SVN would also be fine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, the closest is to print the first line of the description ([`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm)) of a version:

```
cleartool describe –fmt "%c" afile | head -1
```

From [fmt_ccase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), "`%c`" display the associated comment.

This differ from the UCM activities (which are grouping several versions together): [they do have an "headline" (title)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623639/6309).